# Changing currency in a form

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to change the currency settings on my form, but the instructions say to click on the form's title and then change the drop down ... and nothing happens when I click on the form title.

Does anyone know how to update this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Cognito Forms support. On your form's build page, you can click the Form Settings button in the bottom green bar. This should open up your form's settings on the left-hand side of the page. The currency option is at the bottom of this pane underneath the Developer Mode option. You may need to scroll down to see it.

If you need additional help, please submit a [support request](https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/) and we'll take a look at what is going on.